# Lucene Query doesn't work after delete and adding same doc

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have two index folder, then delete all docs from second folder documents which storing in first directory, then adding, but without few documents.
In my case, I delete, then add the same document. Then I create
TermQuery(new Term(my_field, my_data)),
but the result is 0. But if I  create MathcAllDocsQuery(), the document appears in ScoreDocs array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this related to Solr in any way?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes.

Comment: @ArmagedechOfficial Sorry for not being clear; _how_ is this related to Solr? Add relevant code to your question so that people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MatsLindh im just creating indexes and push it to solr. idk how to to attach right code snippet. But this problem reproduce in Lucene query too.